# Calculation groups. How to calculate the difference between two items?

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, tabular-editor

I've created two calculation items in my calculation groups
MTD PY and MTD. They both work and display correctly.

However, I'm now trying to find out the variance between the two calculations and it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried both of the following:

```
[MTD] - [MTD PY]

SELECTEDMEASURE() - [MTD PY]
```

I am getting the following error message

[image: error message]

Comment: This is an error for a measure that does not exist.